# How do I test a model with a polymorphic belongs_to association in isolation?

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

Up front, I'm using:

- Ruby 2.3.1
- Rails 5
- rspec-rails 3.5

I've set up a mountable Rails engine with a polymorphic model that I want to use in other engines. The model class looks like this:

```ruby
module Geo
  class Location < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
  end
end
```

In my specs I'd like to make sure that I have a valid model, however, within the engine I have no other model that is associated with `Geo::Location`.

How can I set up a dummy class for testing validity (`belongs_to` require presence) or what are good testing strategies that you have used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Shoulda gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) and it's `belong_to` matcher (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#activerecord-matchers). Something like:

```
it "has a polymorphic relationship" do
  expect(subject).to belong_to(:locatable)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write this is:

```
describe YourClass do
  it { is_expected.to belong_to(:locatable) }
end
```